# How to print a type vector<tuple<string, int, int>> to screen c++?

Tags: c++, vector, tuples, std

Let's say I have

```
std::vector<std::tuple<string ,int ,int>> tupleVector;
tupleVector.push_back(std::tuple<string ,int ,int>("Joe", 2, 3));
tupleVector.push_back(std::tuple<string ,int ,int>("Bob", 4, 5));
```

How can I iterate on the vector to print all values of this vector containing a tuple?

Comment: You didn't put much effort into this question. Your code doesn't come close to compiling.

Comment: You should also use `tupleVector.emplace_back("test", 2, 3);` instead of `push_back`, is much cleaner, faster, and better for current situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just iterate the `vector`, printing each `tuple` value using `cout`:

```cpp
for (const auto& i : tupleVector) {
  cout << get<0>(i) << ", " << get<1>(i) << ", " << get<2>(i) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to break the problem into two steps. First think about how to print just the tuple, then think about how to print the vector. Here is how I'd do it:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s,
                         const std::tuple<std::string, int, int>& t) {
  s << "(" << std::get<0>(t) << "," << std::get<1>(t) << "," <<
      std::get<2>(t) << ")";
  return s;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s,
                         const std::vector<std::tuple<
                         std::string, int, int> >& v) {
  s << "[";
  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < v.size(); idx++) {
    s << v[idx];
    if (idx < v.size() - 1) {
      s << ",";
    }
  }
  s << "]";
  return s;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, int, int> > v;
  v.emplace_back("hello", 3, 4);
  v.emplace_back("goodbye", 45, 67);

  std::cout << v << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This method overrides the operator<< for the tuple and the vector. Printing the vector will loop through the vector calling the operator<< for each tuple.

The output will be:

```
[(hello,3,4),(goodbye,45,67)]
```

Comment: `v.emplace_back("hello", 3, 4);` looks cleaner (and it is actually a tad faster)

Answer (score 1):

for pretty printing of any array of any item (including tuples), something like this.

Note: this program written in c++11. c++14 would make it easier to iterate the tuple without recursion.

example project here: http://goo.gl/9okLTB

example output:

```
Hello World                                                                                                                                                                             
{ hello, 1, 2 }                                                                                                                                                                         
{ { hello, 3, 4 }, { world, 5, 6 } }
```

fully compilable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


namespace detail {
    template<typename Stream>
    struct printer {
        printer(Stream& os)
        : _os ( os )
        {}

        ~printer() {
            _os << " }";
        }

        template<class X>
        void operator()(const X& x) {
            if (_first) {
                _os << "{ ";
                _first = false;
            }
            else {
                _os << ", ";
            }
            _os << x;
        }
    private:
        Stream& _os;
        bool _first = true;    
    };

    template<size_t index, size_t limit>
    struct print_loop
    {
        template<class Stream, class...Args>
        void operator()(detail::printer<Stream>&& print, const std::tuple<Args...>& tuple) const
        {
            print(std::get<index>(tuple));
            print_loop<index+1, limit>()(std::forward<detail::printer<Stream>>(print), tuple);
        }
    };

    template<size_t limit>
    struct print_loop<limit, limit>
    {
        template<class Stream, class...Args>
        void operator()(detail::printer<Stream>&& print, const std::tuple<Args...>& tuple) const
        {

        }    
    };
}

template<class Stream>
detail::printer<Stream> make_printer(Stream& os)
{
    return detail::printer<Stream>(os);
}




template<class Stream, class...Args>
void print_elements(detail::printer<Stream>&& printer, const std::tuple<Args...>& tuple)
{

    detail::print_loop<0, sizeof...(Args)>()(std::forward<detail::printer<Stream>>(printer), tuple);
}

template<class...Args>
void tuple_print(std::ostream& os, const std::tuple<Args...>& tuple)
{
    print_elements(make_printer(os), tuple);
}

template<class...Args>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::tuple<Args...>& tuple)
{
    tuple_print(os, tuple);
    return os;
}

template<class T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    auto print = make_printer(os);
    for(const auto& item : vec) {
        print(item);
    }
}

using namespace std;


int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   auto x = make_tuple(string { "hello" }, 1, 2);
   cout << x << endl;

   auto y = vector<tuple<string, int, int>> {
    make_tuple(string { "hello" }, 3, 4),
    make_tuple(string { "world" }, 5, 6)
   };
   cout << y << endl;

   return 0;
}
```